# error method activate of object worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want sheet 6 to be displayed when I open the Excel file, but when the following code is executed:
(run time eroor1004
method activate of obeject _ worksheet field)
How can this error be corrected?

````
Sheet6.Activate
End Sub```
````

Comment: Please share the complete relevant code from `Sub...` to `...: End Sub` and its location (e,g, `Sheet1`, `ThisWorkbook`, `Module1`...). About the error, surely you can write 50 or so characters without multiple typos.

Comment: I've noticed in your previous question you don't provide further info when asked and you're not accepting answers (using the tick if it solves your problem).  You're more likely to get responses when you respond as well.

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`
`Worksheets("rahnama").Activate`
`Range(“A1”).Select`
`End Sub`